# How does one set a proxy in lazybones?

Tags: groovy, proxy, gradle

I'm behind a firewall and lazybones can't reach its repository without a proxy.

I've searched the source and can't seem to find any reference to a proxy that seems to be relevant.

Comment: Is the anonymous edit pending on this question made by you, but not logged in?

Comment: yes, i added the comment (but wasn't logged in) to try to clarify the question (and to show that the answer below does not answer the question).

Answer (score 2):

Support was officially added in version 0.8.1 of Lazybones, albeit via a general mechanism to add arbitrary system properties to the application in its configuration file, `~/.lazybones/config.groovy`.

You can read about the details [in the project README](https://github.com/pledbrook/lazybones/blob/master/README.md#user-content-setting-a-proxy-and-other-system-properties-since-081), but in essence, simply add the following to your `config.groovy` file:

```
systemProp {
    http {
        proxyHost = "localhost"
        proxyPort = 8181
    }
    https {
        proxyHost = "localhost"
        proxyPort = 8181
    }
}
```

You can use the `systemProp.` prefix to add any system properties to Lazybones, similar to the way it works in Gradle.

Comment: To run this configuration properly in Lazybones 0.8.1, use the proxyPort value has STRING... This is fixed in 0.8.2, according: https://github.com/pledbrook/lazybones/pull/155

Comment: How can I configure user authentication? I'm using two more lines 'proxyUser' and 'proxyPassword' in config.groovy but I'm still receiving 407 error.

Answer (score 1):

Is [that](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html) what You're looking for? Basically You need to add some properties to `gradle.properties` file.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Cygwin on Windows and I have modified the last line of

```
~/.gvm/lazybones/current/bin/lazybones
```

to say

```
exec "$JAVACMD" "${JVM_OPTS[@]}" -classpath "$CLASSPATH" "-Dhttp.proxyHost=127.0.0.1" "-Dhttp.proxyPort=8888" "-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost|127.0.0.1" uk.co.cacoethes.lazybones.LazybonesMain "$@"
```

Please note the quotes around the options. It works very well with my local Fiddler installation.

I have found no better way to enable proxy support due to the way the script is using eval. Maybe a more experienced shell script programmer can come up with a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get out through the proxy setting the environment settings of

Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dhttp.proxyHost=127.0.0.1 -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 
  -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts="lmig.com" -Dhttps.proxyHost=127.0.0.1 -Dhttps.proxyPort=8080

unfortunately my environment requires authentication so I couldn't provide the complete proxy this way. I first ran "OWASP Zed Attach Proxy (ZAP)" which allowed me to run a proxy on my own machine (at port 8080) which then provided the complete authentication required.

This was able to then run the complete "lazybones list" command which retrieved the contents of the respositories.

Unfortunately I was not able to create an application from those templates becuase bintray required a login (though an anonymous login would do) and couldn't seem to get an additional level of authentication (I received "Unauthorized" from bintray)

Comment: Unfortunately I never saw this comment. Authenticated proxies will be supported in version 0.8.3. Sorry, I just wasn't aware of what needed to be done to support them. I thought it was automatic if you add the `http.proxyUser/Password` properties.